# Why does my image not show properly after clicking? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I'm having this code:

```
Private Sub FormatMouseOver_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles FormatMouseOver.MouseClick
    FormatClicked.Enabled = True
    FormatClicked.Visible = True
    BigLettersNoClicked.Enabled = True
    BigLettersNoClicked.Visible = True
    FormatMouseOver.Visible = False
    FormatMouseOver.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

all the variables are images stored in pictureBoxes. The first one mentioned (FormatClicked) does show and enables itself properly, however the secound one (BigLettersNoClicked) doesn't do anything. The two pictureBoxes overlap, the BigLettersNoClicked is exactly one layer above FormatClicked. I tried putting it on any other place in the project and it still doesn't work.

Just to clarify: FormatMouseOver disabling works fine, and there are no errors during debuging

Subsequent question: since i'm new to the vb.net, can anyone explain to me, what is the difference between MouseClick and Click events?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, MSDN provides a good summary about that topic:

Maybe this helps you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx